# Migrate mailboxes between Plesk 9.5.4

Tags: email, migration, plesk

I have 2 identical Plesk 9.5.4 platforms on 2 webservers. Both have the same domain supposing domain.com
First platform has only emails for domain.com and second platform has only http dir domain.com. I want to migrate mail from one to another. For second platform has http dir + mail.

Seems visible solution it is run "New migration" and select "Only mail accounts with e-mail messages". But there is a problem. Mailboxes consist ~9 Gb mails and migration process work 1 hour. But after all I see "Complete with no errors" as well as no one mailboxes in domain.com -> "Mail accounts". My question is why selected way "Only mail accounts with e-mail messages" not work?

If I selected "All settings and content." the http became empty because it is empty on first platform and I will lost the site but get new emails :) But it is mean some downtime with site work while I restore site folder, no best way.

Is there a way to migrate only emails with minimum pain and without downtime?

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you try to migrate it through command line. First create your all email account on your second server and then migrate your mail directory from your old server to new server. Your mail directory path should be **/var/qmail/mailnames/DOMAIN/USER/Maildir**